# alembic distribution was not found error

Tags: python, alembic

I am using alembic with virtualenv in a django project, I have created a virtual environment in path

```
/ENV
/myproject
```

inside my project I have a configs/development.ini file in which I define alembic parameters

```
script_location = ../ENV/bin/alembic
```

when I try to run alembic

```
alembic -c configs/development.ini upgrade head
```

I am getting the following error

```
The 'Mako' distribution was not found and is required by alembic
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install Alembic and its dependencies (such as Mako) properly.  Inside your virtualenv, run the command `pip install alembic`, which will automatically pull in dependencies for each package.